# How to restrict order in website wise in magento 2.2.0

Tags: orders, websites, magento2.2.0

I have created two websites and install track order.

1. website1
2. website2

but I have placed an order in website1 and track order working now properly but one issue website2 order display track order.

**now how to restrict the order in website2.
please advance thanks for the help.**

Comment: have you install track order custom module right?

Comment: yes i have install module track order.

Comment: can you please share module url?

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/mconnectsolutions-trackorder.html

Comment: what is issue with track order?

Comment: now website1 order display in website3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71065/discussion-between-ravindrasinh-zala-and-abdul).

Comment: Pls check my ans and let me know any issue

Comment: but one question public function working so i will not change private

Comment: please accept my question.@Abdul

Comment: Ok it is working both function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is module bug. I have fixed module bug

Open file `Mconnectsolutions\Trackorder\Controller\Index\Info.php` and replace

code in function  `private function getOrder()` at line number `59`

**from**:

```
    private function getOrder()
    {
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getParams()) {
            $orderId = $data["order"];
            $email = $data["email"];
            $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
            $cEmail = $orderData->getCustomerEmail();


            if ($cEmail == $email) {
                $url = $this->link->getWindowUrl($orderData);
                $parts = parse_url($url);
                parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
                $hash = $query['hash'];

                if ($hash && $hash != '') {
                    $shippingInfoModel = $this->shippingInfoFactory->create()->loadByHash($hash);
                    $this->trackingData = $shippingInfoModel;
                }
                return $orderData;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**To:**

```
    private function getOrder()
    {
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getParams()) {
            $orderId = $data["order"];
            $email = $data["email"];
            $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
            $cEmail = $orderData->getCustomerEmail();

            $storeManager = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
            $currentStoreId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();

            if ($cEmail == $email && $orderData->getStoreId() == $currentStoreId) {
                $url = $this->link->getWindowUrl($orderData);
                $parts = parse_url($url);
                parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
                $hash = $query['hash'];

                if ($hash && $hash != '') {
                    $shippingInfoModel = $this->shippingInfoFactory->create()->loadByHash($hash);
                    $this->trackingData = $shippingInfoModel;
                }
                return $orderData;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```